# Using RPi Zero W as Bluetooth smart device

Tags: bluetooth, pi-zero-w, remote

I'm trying to setup my RPi Zero W as a Terrarium Controller and I want to be able to create an Android app to control the settings and and such over Bluetooth. I've found tons of tutorials on setting up the RPi as a Bluetooth server, but none of them quite fit what I'm trying to do and I'm not sure how to adapt them to work as intended. I do want it to be secure, by either a single-paired device or requiring a code input or something to that nature. What would be the simplest solution to this? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to do this would be setting up a Bluetooth socket server in Python, adding a simple communication over it - then adding some security algorithm, such as basic password check or even data (or text, if you wish to make it command-oriented) encryption of traffic - Python is simple and quick way to perform these tasks with little to no difficulty. Note that Python is language that only server has to work with - Android app does not need it to connect and communicate.

Comment: I like the idea. Could you perhaps elaborate, and maybe even link a tutorial on doing this? Thanks.

Comment: @Timberwolf I didn't do it myself yet, but it was added as a feature of Python 3.3. https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/14725/bluetooth.BluetoothSocket <- here are some code parts of how it should look like, but it's very similar to regular socket server which is very friendly explained here: https://realpython.com/python-sockets/. Try to make regular one first, then move onto Bluetooth version with Python client to finally look for creation of proper Android client. Remember - Python is one of many ways to do this, if it won't work for you think of other languages.

Comment: OK, I'll look into that. If I can make it work, I'll mark your answer as the accepted answer.